# Display Logged In User Data

Tags: python, flask, session, jinja2

I'm creating a login and register site using flask and I want to display the name of the user that is logged in.

Here's what I have in my main.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session, redirect, url_for
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
import MySQLdb
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
key = Fernet.generate_key()
print(key)

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "123456"

app.config["MYSQL_HOST"] = "localhost"
app.config["MYSQL_USER"] = "root"
app.config["MYSQL_PASSWORD"] = ""
app.config["MYSQL_DB"] = "azurcam"

db = MySQL(app)



@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'username' in request.form and 'password' in request.form:
            username = request.form['username']
            password = request.form['password']
            cursor = db.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=%s AND password =%s", (username,password))
            info = cursor.fetchone()
            print(info)
            if info is not None:
                if info['email'] == username and info['password'] == password:
                    session['loginsuccess'] = True
                    return redirect(url_for('profile'))
            else:
               return redirect(url_for('index'))

    return render_template("login.html")


@app.route('/new', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def new_user():
    if request.method == "POST":
        if "one" in request.form and "two" in request.form and "three" in request.form:
            username = request.form['one']
            email = request.form['two']
            password = request.form['three']
            cur = db.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO azurcam.users(username, email, password)VALUES(%s, %s, %s)",(username, email, password))
            db.connection.commit()
            return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template("registeration.html")
@app.route('/new/profile')
def profile():
    if session['loginsuccess'] == True:
        return render_template("profile.html")

@app.route('/new/logout')
def logout():
    session.pop('loginsuccess',None)
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and in a html template, I want to display the name of the user that is logged in. I tried:

```
<form action="/new/logout">
    <h1>Login Successful</h1>
    <label> Welcome to your profile {{username}}</label>
    <button type="submit">LOGOUT</button>
</form>
```

but its not showing anything, can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It's not showing anything, or is only the username missing?

Comment: Its showing everything but the username

Comment: OK, I think the main thing is that you have to 'pass' the username to profile.html, so you would do: 'return render_template("profile.html", username=username)'. But, honestly, I forget if the username variable will carry over automatically from your index function, or if you'll have to make it a session variable.

Answer (score 0):

To display a value you need to pass it to `render_template("foo.html", username=username)` as a kwarg. Try looking into [Flask-Login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#login-example) where you can access the logged in user's attributes via [current_user](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#login-example) i.e `{{ current_user.username }}`. Another option would be saving it in Flask's [session](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/#sessions) then `{{ session["username"] }}`.